# squid proxy error 403 tcp how to fix

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, ubuntu-14.04, squid, http-proxy

hello guys i am installing squid as HTTP proxy for scraping urls from google with a tool i have configured every thing  but when i am connecting to squid it is giving tcp 403 error i have ubuntu14.04 and i have not changed its default settings just change HTTP_access deny all to allow and all are same i want to use that proxy for scraping purpose what should be config file of it please help me out searching stuff from more then 2 days now.

```
http_port 3128

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC 1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC 1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443          # https

acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http

acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
```

Comment: I think this link might be of help <https://serverfault.com/questions/322625/squid-403s-every-request-as-an-http-proxy>

Answer (score 15):

Error 403 means Forbidden Access.

Change last line in your question:

```
http_access deny all
```

to

```
http_access allow all
```

This is basically changing your policy from whitelist (deny all sites except those explicitly allowed) to blacklist (allow access to all sites except those explicitly denied). So you should add your acl above it.

Comment: "Blacklist" is not "deny all sites", but the opposite: "allows through all elements [...] except those explicitly mentioned" (Wikipedia). Same for "whitelist". Actually, `http_access deny all` is whitelisting (deny all except explicitly mentioned) and `http_access allow all` is blacklisting (allow all except explicitly mentioned).

Comment: This answer is misleading. The `all` acl element does not "allow access **to** all sites" but allows access **from** any IP to use your proxy. So by changing the line to `http_access allow all`, everyone in the world will be able to use your proxy for good or bad things. If doing so, you should at least add an authentication measure.